# Program does not work properly when double click on the .jar file

Tags: java, jar, jvm, double-click

I have coded a little Program that asks for username and a password and check the inputs with a mysql database.
In the Eclipse IDE it works fine. The program is connecting and it can login or say the inputs are invalid.
But when i export my project as .jar it isnt working properly when i double click on it. It shows the GUI and i can input the 2 Strings but when i click on the Login Button nothing happens. I also tried to execute it via console with "java -jar project.jar" and to my surprise its working fine, no errors and i can login.

I also tried it on different Systems. On some it's working. My Laptop can open the file without any problem.
I already re-installed JRE.

Comment: In addition i used jarfix but the project still isnt working properly. But via console or IDE there is no problem.

Comment: Redirect error output to a text file. There could be dozens of reasons why it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps, the `java` executable used by the command line test was a different than registered with the doubleclick handler. Use the taskmanager to inspect both processes and check which java(w) executable they are running. To be on the safe side, in case of delegating launchers, it’s worth using the process explorer to check which jvm.dll has been loaded into either process.